# Parse REST how to create object with user pointer?

Tags: rest, parse-platform

Using **[shiki/kaiseki](https://github.com/shiki/kaiseki)** to interact with Parse API. How can I save a user pointer to an object?

If I query users:

```
kaisekiClient.getObjects('_User', function (err, res, json) {
  json[0].objectId 
  // 'pBIb9ncQDv'
})
```

But if I try to create an object it errors.

```
kaisekiCient.createObject('Thing', {
  user: {
    __type: 'Pointer',
    className: '_User',
    objectId: 'pBIb9ncQDv'
  }
}

// { code: 111, 
//   error: 'invalid type for key user, expected *User, but got *_User' }
```

Are references supposed to use `User` instead of `_User`? Why would `_User` be needed as the className for fetching objects, but not for referencing them?

Comment: looks like your column 'user' is set up wrong.  It should show as a Pointer<_User> not Pointer<User>.

Comment: how would I fix the column?

Comment: Drop it and re-add it (or just drop it, and run this code which will automatically add it.)

Comment: Thanks @Fosco. If you add as an answer to drop on parse website, I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your column 'user' is set up wrong. It should show as a Pointer<_User> not Pointer<User>.  Drop the column from the Data Browser and re-add it (or just drop it, and run this code which will automatically add it.)